# Rspec root_path redirecting to unauthenticated path after login_as(user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

When I login as user in rspec my `root_path` is still redirecting to `unauthenticated` path. I am wondering why and how to fix it?

If I have routes set like this:

```
devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root to: "some_page#some_action", as: :user_root
  end

  unauthenticated :user do
    root to: "devise/registrations#new"
  end
end
```

And if my rspec looks something like this:

```
describe "Main Page", :type => :feature do

  let(:current_user) { create(:user) }

  context "As signed in user" do

    before do
      login_as(current_user)
    end

    describe "Show main page" do

      before do
        visit root_path
      end

      it "Should be able to see main page" do
        expect(page).to have_content('Main Page')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Why my rspec is redirecting to a path of `unauthenticated` user (`devise/registrations#new`) instead of root path for `authenticated` user: `some_page#some_action` when I call:

```
before do
  visit root_path
end
```

Comment: Maybe by any chance `visit root_path` executes before `login_as(current_user)`? Did you try to put `login_as(current_user)` and `visit root_path` in the same `before` block?

Comment: Tried it, and the error stayed the same. Maybe good to mention is that this used to work correctly in the past and it is not anymore.

Comment: Did you update gem versions recently? Or did you edit/refactor `login_as` method?

Comment: @VAD I don't remember if I updated the gem recently. Has some new version introduced some new changes? Also, I haven't edited nor refactored the `login_as` method

Comment: Ok, I've got an idea. Not sure if it's dumb or brilliant. But we'll see. Try to name your `current_user` variable with some else name, for example `let(:my_user) { create(:user) }`. Don't forget to change an old name throughout your spec file. I think it's all about your `current_user` variable may somehow conflict with `current_user` method provided by Devise.

Comment: heh :) good idea, and it might have worked in some cases, but it didn't work in this case :/

Comment: Sad:). Still we have to check if your `login_as` method actually performs user log in. So you could run spec like this `expect(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(current_user)`. Put it along with the spec in your question code. It must expose if `login_as` works properly or not.